# echoing arabic string from database like this?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching data with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` the string is Arabic it's  echoing like this `?????`

I tried encoding but not worked.

```
    $dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tedmon") or die("Error 3: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("SET character-set utf8");
    $sqlForStudent = "SELECT `MONITORING_PROVINCE`,count(*) FROM `student_interview` group by `MONITORING_PROVINCE`";
    $sqlForadmin = "SELECT `pro`,count(*) FROM `ttc_admin_interview` group by `pro`";
    $sqlForteacherev = "SELECT `pro`,count(*) FROM `ttc_teachers_evaluation` group by `pro`";
    $sqlForteacherint = "SELECT `pro`,count(*) FROM `ttc_teachers_interview`  group by `pro`";

    $studentset = mysql_query($sqlForStudent);
    $adminset = mysql_query($sqlForadmin);
    $teacherevset = mysql_query($sqlForteacherev);
    $teacherintset = mysql_query($sqlForteacherint);

while($teacherevres = mysql_fetch_array($teacherevset)){
          echo $teacherevres['pro'];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET character-set utf8");
```

To

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Make sure you have added `charset` in `head` your page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

> **Note** `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0

Comment: Worked for me perfectly Thanks ;)

Comment: can you tell me the reason why it doesn't worked with that methods i write what is deference between my parameters and your's

Comment: @user2620132 your query was not correct. You can see `'` was missing in first changed line and there was extra `-` between `character-set` on 2nd line.